# Create List of IRepository<T> in an interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface and I want to create a list of Repositories using generics. However, the `T` next to `IRepository` has `The type or namespace T could not be found`. How can I create a property that is a list of generic repositories?

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IRepository<T>> Repositories { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to specify `IDataAccess<T>` in order for the T type information to be propagated down to the `Repositories` property. Otherwise, the compiler has no way to determine what the type is.

Comment: I did `IDataAccess<T> where T : class` and the compiler is not throwing the error anymore. Thank you.